# Evaluating 0 when trying to find the smallest integer fails

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, zero

I'm trying to do a simple sorting of my own (I know `Array.Sort()` exists), receiving a user input array and then calling the method `sortMyArray()` to sort the numbers from smallest to largest. Which does what intended, *except* for when I try to find the smallest number of an array that contains 0.

As you will see: I'm initialising the variable `smallest` to the value `int.MaxValue` at each iteration, but if the array contains a 0, it stays set to to the `int.MaxValue`.

```
static int findSmallest(int[] original, int[] sorted, int smallest)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; i++)
     {
         if (original[i] < smallest & !sorted.Contains(original[i]))
         {
              smallest = original[i];
         }
      }
      return smallest;
}

static int[] sortMyArray(int[] original)
{
       int[] sorted = new int[original.Length];

       for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; i++)
       {
            int smallest = int.MaxValue;
            smallest = findSmallest(original, sorted, smallest);
            sorted[i] = smallest;
       }
       return sorted;
 }

 sortMyArray(inputArray);
```

My question is, how can I make sure 0 is properly handled?

The code behaves as intended for positive and negative integer values, but what is causing the 0 to not work?

**Edit:** For example, if the inputArray contains `{5, -1, 7, 0, 33}`, then the method will return it sorted as such: `{-1, 5, 7, 33, 2147483647}`.

Comment: Since `sorted` is `int` array, it's initialized by default with `0`es. Hence `sorted.Contains(0)` will be always `true`. Not sure why you need that `Contains`, it's definitely wrong to me.

Comment: It's not working as expected because when you initialize an `int` array, all values are `0`. so the check `!sorted.Contains(original[i])` is meaningless. Also even, if it worked for zeros, it will not work if your array contains duplicate values

Comment: And apart the issue with the `sorted` array, you are also assuming that each element only occurs once within the original array.

Comment: What you need is to learn to debug.

Comment: @IvanStoev that makes sense. I need the `Contains`, to know if I've already not sorted the current number. As in, once I've found the smallest number in the `original` array, I no longer want to evaluate it, I want to find the next smallest number after that. Perhaps you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: The check for `!sorted.Contains(original[i])` is, because without it, `sorted` would be filled with **only** the smallest item of `original`.

Comment: @Reniuz genius comment, that helps me understand the problem I'm having completely.

Comment: @user10192196 - you probably want another array (probably pre-initialized with all `-1`), where you store the *index* of all the items of `original` you already put into `sorted`. (and check `!indexes.Contains(i)`)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Just create a copy of the original array and use the inplace algorithm from the link.

Comment: Well, little genius, if you DID debug, evaluate variables and check why your if statement failing, you would find the problem by yourself.

Comment: @user10192196 - Reniuz is not *totally* wrong. You could've found the the error by setting a breakpoint when you enter `sortMyArray` and then go step-by-step (`F11`) through the whole algorithm. It helps to test it with very small arrays first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `!sorted.Contains(original[i])` you skip over any value that is already in the array.  `sorted` is initialized to all `0`'s so it will never set `smallest = 0`.  In your last iteration in `sortMyArray`, `smallest` will be equal to `int.Max`.  Note, this will also happen when you have the same element twice.  Since you want to implement your own sorting method (and not use `Array.Sort`), you should look into various sorting algorithms (i.e. Merge Sort, Quick Sort, etc.) as yours won't work as intended.

Comment: This answer was helpful in understanding the reason for my problem (That is,  "duh, int arrays initialise to 0, that is why"). Understanding the underlaying reason as to why a 0 was produced made it a quick fix by initialising the array with - you guessed it - a value that did not have a chance to exist in the array. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help!  Glad I didn't come across as condescending